# What error would this be called?

Tags: punctuation

> "I have completed my homework, and have nothing to do now."

Placing the comma before 'and' would be incorrect since the second clause is dependent and therefore doesn't require a comma, right? I was just wondering what this mistake would be called in technical terms or if it's just called a misuse of a comma.

Comment: I would call it mispunctuation.

Comment: With a heavy independent clause before the 'and', where a pause might be welcome before 'and have nothing to do now', I'd probably brave the flak and add a comma. Or an ellipsis. Or perhaps rewrite. // This comes under the title of 'comma usage and compound predicates'; see this article at the APA style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/09/comma-usage-and-compound-predicates.html). They endorse your 'rule', giving the logic behind it: 'This comma adds a pause that creates distance between the subject and the predicate, so you should not include a comma in this case'. But I might ...

Comment: _desire_ to distance the second statement from the first, giving contrast or adding a dramatic pause for thought.